# Error in the below given program pls solve it

Tags: java

i want the output of the program to be R . pandya if i enter rachit pandya but instead it is saying that the length of the entered sentence (rachit pandya) is 6 but it should be 13 to work my program can anyone please tell me the error
the code is given..

```
public class surName {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Name-:");
        String s = sc.next();
        s = " " + s;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
                System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i + 1)) + ".");
            }
        }
        int a = s.lastIndexOf(" ");
        for (int i = a + 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i literally opened this question just to downvote, "pls solve it" is not an adequate question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
String s = sc.next()
```

use

```
String s = sc.nextLine();//would read your last and first name i.e. whole line as one String
```

as [next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) method would just read "rachit" token (anything before default delimiter space) and not whole line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("name?");
    String name = sc.nextLine();

    String output[] = name.split(" ");

    System.out.println(output[0].charAt(0)+". " + output[1]);
```